# Is there a way of specifying a css grid row to grow with content, up to a maximum value?

Tags: css, sass, css-grid

Right now I am having trouble specifying a row in a css grid. What I am trying to achieve is a row that grows with its content, but up to a maximum value. Something like this:

min(min-content, 80vh)

However, I cannot use min-content in a min() css function, has it is not a number.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: max-height: 80vh on the content?

Comment: Just dont use a row. All rows will grow with the content to start with. Use columns only

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose we want to have a grid that consists of three size columns and we want to determine the size of the three rows so that their height is at least 100 pixels and the maximum height is free for them, that is, whatever the content inside them can be. For this, we can easily use the minmax function.

Is this what you are looking for?
If it is, take a look at this code:

```
.grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: minmax(100px, auto) minmax(100px, auto) minmax(100px, auto);
}
```

Instead of auto, you can use any value to specify the maximum size.

I recommend you take a look at these two links, [grid-template-rows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows) and [minmax()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax).